# ASCII code shows when I share an article off Wordpress to Twitter or Linkedin

Tags: wordpress, twitter, ascii, linkedin-api

Images for reference.

[image: Header section with rendered content]
[image: What's happening textfield block]

This is in Wordpress site i'm working on. Not sure if there is something I can do with Javascript to convert that code into quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );` to the function.php, this fixed the problem.